# is using two UARTs wiser compared to I2C and UART with Arduino + Xbee + BNO055 Sensor

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, xbee

#### Hardware

1. Arduino Nano
2. XBee Pro S1 (802.15.4) Modules
3. [Adafruit BNO055 Absolute Orientation Sensor](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor/overview)

#### Purpose

I want to send the Euler angles and Linear Acceleration angles to the a central **XBee Coordinator** (can be connected to a Computer or a Single Board Computer) every **100 ms**

Since the BNO055 has **SDA** and **SCL** pins for I<sup>2</sup>C how will the performance of the Nano matter when sensor data is acquired from the BNO sensor and send to XBee module which will be connected to the **Hardware Serial UART** Port?

An interesting observation was that if one:

> Shorts the PS1 pin to 3.3V for the BNO055, the **SDA** and **SCL** will function as **RX** and **TX** pins for UART. 
>   [source](https://learn.adafruit.com/bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor-with-raspberry-pi-and-beaglebone-black/hardware#raspberry-pi)

In terms of interfacing, I can think of the **Xbee** now connected to the **Hardware Serial Port** and perhaps the BNO sensor will can be connected to the Nano via `SoftwareSerial` port. But will that serve any better purpose in terms of performance and data acquisition i.e. using two *Asynchronous* Serial Ports compared to one?

Answer (score 1):

All software serial solutions are much less efficient than `HardwareSerial` (i.e., `Serial`).  `SoftwareSerial` is particularly bad, because it disables interrupts for long periods of time.  95% of the MCU time can be spent twiddling its thumbs, waiting for each bit to come in.

Using the I2C interface for the BNO055 means that the Arduino hardware will independently and concurrently handle each *byte* of data from the BNO055 and from `Serial` (i.e., the XBee).  Your sketch can continue to do other things while each byte arrives.  This is most efficient.

Software serial port libraries handle each *bit* of data, sometimes to the exclusion of all other activity.

Comment: So even though I2C being a synchronous serial protocol and UART being asynchronous; results might tend to be good in status quo than 2 asynch. modes on the Arduino.

Comment: @Shan-Desai, the processor load is **much** less with I2C+UART.  Sync/asynch does not matter, because the peripherals (I2C controller and USART) operate independently from the CPU.  It's like hardware-accelerated graphics vs. software rendering.